# Adding light to scene has no effect

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was just starting to play around with Three.JS but I am stuck at the beginning. When I add a light to the scene, it has no effect.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera 45, # View Angle
  800 / 640, # Aspect
  0.1, # Near
  10000 # Far

camera.position.z = 300

scene = new THREE.Scene()
renderer.setSize 800, 640

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

createSphere = (radius = 50, segments = 16, rings = 16) ->
  sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings)
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial {
    color: 0xCC000F,
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
    ambient: 0x555555,
    specular: 0xffffff
  }

  new THREE.Mesh sphere, material 

light = new THREE.PointLight(0x0040ff)
light.position.x = 10
light.position.y = 50
light.position.z = 300
light.intensity  = 0.1

object = createSphere()
scene.add new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0000F0)
scene.add light
scene.add object

draw = ->
  time = new Date().getTime() * 0.0005;
  light.position.x = Math.sin(time * 0.7) * 30
  object.rotation.x += 0.02
  renderer.render scene, camera
  requestAnimationFrame draw

draw()
```

I also created a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nils_r/mNq2a/) with the parsed js.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MeshBasicMaterial doesn't support lighting, you should change your material. A basic material supporting lighting is MeshLambertMaterial, I have [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mNq2a/1/) your jsfiddle.

More detailed example:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_lights_pointlights.html